# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'onGoogleReady' using angular-ui's ui.maps with Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-ui

I'm trying to use [angular-ui's](http://angular-ui.github.io/) [ui-map](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map) library with Angular.js and receive the error

"
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'onGoogleReady' using ui.maps with Angular.js
".

I understand I need to include :

```
function onGoogleReady() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("map"), ['app.ui-map']);
}
```

but where and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function initCall() {
 console.log("Google maps api initialized.");
   angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("map"), ['doc.ui-map']);
}

angular.module('doc.ui-map', ['ui.map', 'prettifyDirective'])
 .controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.myMarkers = [];

$scope.mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.784, -78.670),
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

$scope.addMarker = function ($event, $params) {
  $scope.myMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    map: $scope.myMap,
    position: $params[0].latLng
  }));
};

$scope.setZoomMessage = function (zoom) {
  $scope.zoomMessage = 'You just zoomed to ' + zoom + '!';
  console.log(zoom, 'zoomed');
};

$scope.openMarkerInfo = function (marker) {
  $scope.currentMarker = marker;
  $scope.currentMarkerLat = marker.getPosition().lat();
  $scope.currentMarkerLng = marker.getPosition().lng();
  $scope.myInfoWindow.open($scope.myMap, marker);
};

$scope.setMarkerPosition = function (marker, lat, lng) {
  marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
};
}]) ;
```

**Source :** <kbd>[Demo.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map/blob/master/demo/demo.js)</kbd>

Comment: thank you! great example of implementing the other functions too!