# conditionally bootstrap app in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I have an angularJs web app that uses google maps api v3. I'm using ui-map from angular-ui.

My issue is this, the app needs to function with poor connectivity. I've got offline storage working nicely.

The problem is that ui-map needs google maps to load before loading the angular module like so:

```
function onGoogleReady() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("body"), ['baseApp']);
}
```

... where onGoogleReady() is the google maps api callback.

This throws offline mode out the window since the app doesn't load until Google Maps loads and that won't happen offline.

How could I conditionally load the app with or without ui-map depending on if there's a connection or not?

I've tried running:

```
var app = angular.module('baseApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ui.validate', 'ui.keypress', 'ui.event', 'imageupload', 'LocalStorageModule'])
```

and then

```
function onGoogleReady() {
    app = angular.module('baseApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ui.map', 'ui.validate', 'ui.keypress', 'ui.event', 'imageupload', 'LocalStorageModule'])
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("body"), ['baseApp']);
}
```

to load it again with ui-map when maps loads but anuglar doesn't allow binding to the same element again.

I'm sure there's a nice tidy way to do it, but my angularJS understanding is lacking...

**UPDATE: Here's the solution I found:**

First, don't bind the app in the html (no ng-app)
Next, have an online variable:

```
var isOnline = false;
function onGoogleReady() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("body"), ['baseApp', 'ui.map']);
}
```

Then check if online. If so insert the google maps script which will run the callback with ui-maps, if not bind the app without ui-maps:

```
var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status != '200') {
                    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("body"), ['baseApp']);
                } else {
                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.type = 'text/javascript';
                    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' + 'callback=onGoogleReady';
                    document.body.appendChild(script);
                };
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://thisapp.com", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: will Dependency Injection help?　http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: This will help you , http://stackoverflow.com/a/20278445/2837412

Comment: Neither of those work. What I needed was to either load the module with ui-map if online or without it when offline. I'm updating the original post with the solution I found

Answer (score 0):

Will you probably consider to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). And add a fallback method if maps couldn't be loaded?

Answer (score -1):

Time ago I created a service for my personal project. check it maybe can help you.

https://github.com/SaulBurgos/angularjs-module-googleMaps